# Apache can't reading from documentroot with permissions for www-data

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, permissions

My OS is Linux Mint 17.
My goal is allow reading of /mnt/wwwdata for root and apache only. 
I trying to setup apache document root in directory /mnt/wwwdata, 
with rights 0770 for group wwwadmins, which contains users "root" and "www-data". 
Apache was compiled from sources, not installed with apt-get. It places in /usr/local/apache2.

At this moment apache can't access php files in this directory. When i set 0777 to , it helps.

I suspect, that my compiled apache is another user, than 'www-data'. How I can to know name of apache?

Comment: Is SELinux enabled on the installation?

Comment: Nope, SELinux disabled. Thanks. Problem was solved - thanks to Stony

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally you can set this in your `httpd.conf`. There you can set the:

```
User nobody
Group nobody
```

This is the user and group which will apache2 use on startup.